# Constraints not lining up across different devices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, constraints

I recently realized that my constraints weren't lining up across devices. I started to Google ways to fix this, I can only get some devices to align correctly but others won't. Can someone explain to me on how to do constraints the right way?

Image of devices:
[image]

Comment: What constraints have you set? What result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Not clear..what exactly you trying to achieve. Let us know with screenshot or description the position of each element on screen as desired.

Comment: Looking at your pictures and your question, this is a BROAD question. "Teach me how do to constraints". The answer to this would take an entire community to come together and create a Guide for you to read, which actually has already been done here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ , check Youtube tutorials. etc. Trial and error. Also, make sure you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Also, setting constraints is DIFFEENT from every case to case. If you have a **specific** constraint problem u can ask it. GL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest StackView for this case.

1. Set the height of all your component (email field, password field, login button, reset button, create account button). You should not set a default width since you want it to adjust based on the screen
2. Put email field, password field and login button in a StackView.Remember you have two buttons that are going to be vertically aligned so adjust them to a reasonable width.Add whatever distance you want between the elements.Then set the upper right, left and right constraints.
3. Put reset account button and create account button in a stackView. Add whatever distance you want between the elements. Then set the bottom, left and right Constraints.
4. Now select the first stackView.Press the control button and drag the blue line to the second stack. Add the vertical constraints between them.